# Linear Algebra - Proof of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

I'm stuck in how to proof the follow question.

> Let $V = \mathcal{F}({I},\mathbb{R}) $, where ${I}$ is in the range of $[0,1]$ and $$T = \left\{ \mathcal{f} \in V: f(1) = 0 \right\} $$
>   Is $T$ a vectorial subspace of V?

How can I demonstrate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any $f,g\in V$, then $f(1)=g(1)=0$ so $$(f+g)(1) = f(1)+g(1)=0+0=0$$ so $f+g \in V$ and similary for multipliction with scalar $$(a\cdot f)(1) = af(1)=a\cdot 0=0$$

so $a\cdot f\in V$ also.

Comment: I didn't understand what are the $\mathcal{F}({I}, \mathbb{R})$. Can you explain me more about?

Comment: It is just set of function from I to R, I believe. Anyway you have to look in a source where you took a problem. There must be an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

first I think they must be a mistake in your set, and you mean  $ {T={f∈V:f(1)=0} } $. 
Then you have to ask yourself about axioms of vectorial space. 
Here is a little question: if $ f $ and $ g \in V $ does $ f + g $ belong to V ?